# How can I rotate around a translated object's local coordinate axis using quaternions?

Tags: graphics, directx, linear-algebra

I have the world matrix `object_world` of an object that's been translated somewhere in world space. I would like to rotate around it's local x coordinate axis using quaternions. How can I do this?

Right now I can only rotate around the world x axis like this:

```
XMVECTOR right = XMVectorSet(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
XMVECTOR right_rot_quat = XMQuaternionRotationAxis(right, XM_PIDIV4);
XMMATRIX rot_mat = XMMatrixRotationQuaternion(right_rot_quat);
object_world = object_world * rot_mat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your matrix multiply:

```
object_world = rot_mat * object_world;
```

Matrix transformations are applied to points in the order of composition (i.e., the order of the matrix multiplication).  You said your original order was rotating around the world origin; that indicates your rotation was being applied in the "world" coordinate side of the `object_world` transform.

Since you want to apply it in "object" coordinates instead, the logical thing to try is to move it to the "object" side of the `object_world` transform.

Comment: That did the trick, but I'm confused. Everywhere else in directx I do `object_matrix * modifier_matrix`. Any idea why that's the case? I didn't do any transpose before the code snippet I showed.

Comment: I have added an explanation in the answer.  It's hard to be more specific because you have not provided any context -- but I will say that the order you need your matrices in depends on what you want to do with them.  Perhaps you are trying to do something different there than in the rest of your code?